# Filter range doesn't work on custom grid table dashboard. Magento2

Tags: magento2, grid, filter, grid-layout

In custom table in ui component i use `<filterRange>` for filter `from to`  but it doesn't work.
I need to filter between the date of the column, i.e. show the columns in which there is a match from `01-12-2019` to `05-12-2019`. What is wrong in below code , can someone help me thanks.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * CustomerVw record list UI Component
 * @category  Webkul
 * @package   Webkul_Grid
 * @author    Webkul
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2010-2017 Webkul Software Private Limited (https://webkul.com)
 * @license   https://store.webkul.com/license.html
 */
-->
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Ui/etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">sh_cart_info_grid_list.sh_cart_info_grid_list_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">sh_cart_info_grid_list.sh_cart_info_grid_list_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">grid_records_columns</item>
     <!--   <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New Row</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/addrow</item>
            </item>
        </item>-->
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="sh_cart_info_grid_list_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">sh_cart_info_grid_list_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">cart_info_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">cart_info_id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">cart_info_id</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <container name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
                <item name="stickyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/sticky/toolbar</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks"/>
        <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>
        <filters name="listing_filters">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="columnsProvider" xsi:type="string">sh_cart_info_grid_list.sh_cart_info_grid_list.grid_records_columns</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">sh_cart_info_grid_list.sh_cart_info_grid_list.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.filters</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="templates" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="filters" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="select" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>
                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">sh_cart_info_grid_list.sh_cart_info_grid_list.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                        <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">sh_cart_info_grid_list.sh_cart_info_grid_list.grid_records_columns.${ $.index }:visible</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="observers" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="column" xsi:type="string">column</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <filterRange name="created_date">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">cart_info_id</item> <!-- Column name in DB -->
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item> <!-- Label on grid -->
                        <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">sh_cart_info_listing.sh_cart_info_listing.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
                <filterInput name="from">
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">from</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">From</item>
                            <item name="placeholder" xsi:type="string" translate="true">From</item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </filterInput>
                <filterInput name="to">
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">to</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">To</item>
                            <item name="placeholder" xsi:type="string" translate="true">To</item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </filterInput>
            </filterRange>
        </filters>
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">sh_cart_info_grid_list.sh_cart_info_grid_list.grid_records_columns.ids</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <!-- Mass actions which you want to add in your grid-->
            <action name="delete">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="info/grid/massdelete"/>
                        <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                            <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Do you want to delete selected row record?</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
           <action name="edit">
                <settings>
                    <callback>
                        <target>editSelected</target>
                        <provider>sh_cart_info_grid_list.sh_cart_info_grid_list.grid_records_columns_editor</provider>
                    </callback>
                    <type>edit</type>
                    <label translate="true">Edit</label>
                </settings>
            </action>
        </massaction>
        <paging name="listing_paging">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">sh_cart_info_grid_list.sh_cart_info_grid_list.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">sh_cart_info_grid_list.sh_cart_info_grid_list.grid_records_columns.ids</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </paging>
    </container>
    <columns name="grid_records_columns">
        <settings>
            <editorConfig>
                <param name="clientConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="infoprint/grid/inlineEdit"/>
                    <item name="validateBeforeSave" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </param>
                <param name="indexField" xsi:type="string">cart_info_id</param>
                <param name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</param>
                <param name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">sh_cart_info_grid_list.sh_cart_info_grid_list.grid_records_columns.ids</param>
            </editorConfig>
            <childDefaults>
                <param name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">sh_cart_info_grid_list.sh_cart_info_grid_list.grid_records_columns_editor</item>
                    <item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>
                    <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                        <item name="1" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </param>
            </childDefaults>
        </settings>
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">cart_info_id</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">desc</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>
        <column name="customer_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer Id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="customer_email">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer Email</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="created_date">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created At</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the column like this and you can remove the filter range you already added

```
<column name="created_date" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date">
    <settings>
        <filter>dateRange</filter>
        <dataType>date</dataType>
        <label translate="true">Created </label>
    </settings>
</column>
```

Comment: Marius, thanks a lot